# Pythonic switch within class

Tags: python, dictionary, switch-statement

I am trying to build a switch logic in python.

Based on [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python#) I build the following code:

```
def func(string):
    print(string)

class Switch:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def first_switch(self, case):
        return {
             '1': func('I am case 1'),
             '2': func('I am case 2'),
             '3': func('I am case 3'),
             }.get(case, func('default'))


switch = Switch()
switch.first_switch('2')
```

This will give me the output:

```
I am case 1
I am case 2
I am case 3
default
```

I expected the output to be

```
I am case 2
```

Is this dictionary-case-logic only applicable outside of a class definition or did I miss some additional code? Looks like all dictionary key-value pairs are evaluated at the function call.

Comment: The value is the *result* of calling the function. Why not just store the strings, then call `func` on whatever you get out of the dictionary? Also, why bother with `func` when it's just `print`?

Comment: If you want to store values, func should return its argument. Right now your dictionary is all Nones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're always calling all those functions while building the dictionary. It has nothing to do with classes.

```
d = {'foo': bar()}
```

`bar` is being called here and its return value assigned to `d['foo']`. Remember, this isn't a `switch` statement; it's a dictionary literal that's used to sort of emulate a `switch` statement.

In your case, the function isn't variable, so doesn't have to be included at all:

```
arg = {
    '1': 'I am case 1',
    '2': 'I am case 2',
    '3': 'I am case 3',
}.get(case, 'default')
func(arg)
```

If the function is variable as well, you want to make the dictionary values callables which will call the function *when called*:

```
{'1': lambda: func('I am case 1'), ...}.get(...)()
                    # call the function you got ^^
```

Or perhaps:

```
from functools import partial

{'1': partial(func, 'I am case 1'), ...}.get(...)()
```

Comment: Sorry for the inappropriate example, the function I want to call is indeed variable and thus your `lambda` expression is the key! Thanks for your explanation!